# UIFontMetrics not working for Custom Fonts in iOS 17 with Xcode 15

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, custom-font

I'm creating new app and in that I've to use custom fonts. I'm also planning to support dynamic font types. That's why I'm creating common structure which will provide me fonts at different places of application.
For that I've written following code.

```
static func getHeaderFont(forStyle style: UIFont.TextStyle) -> UIFont {
    guard let font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: UIFont.systemFontSize) else { fatalError("No font found") }
    return UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: style).scaledFont(for: font)
}
```

For this I'm following this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically)
But whatever style I pass to this function I always get same font-size and style.
Here is screenshot of my testing.[image: UIFontMetrics for dynamic size with Custom fonts]
I've tried to get font-size for title2, headline, body, caption2. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried using `let desc = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: style)` and use `desc.pointSize` instead `UIFont.systemFontSize` and check?

Comment: Not yet, But I can easily use ```UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)``` and get pointSize from that. But this time I want to use Apple's approach which they written in their document.

Comment: may be this helps: https://swift.mackarous.com/posts/2023/01/dynamic-type-font-weight/#font-weight

Comment: What is “Apple’s approach”? `UIFontMetrics` and `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)` are for completely different purposes. The former is for getting a system font, the latter is for scaling your custom font. How about describing *exactly* what kind of font you are trying to create?

Answer (score 1):

Your function *will* return different results - it just so happens that the dynamic type size of your phone is the default (standard) size, so everything is scaled by a factor of 1 (aka no change at all).

If you change your dynamic type size in the settings app, you will see that e.g. `.caption1` and `.extraLargeTitle` are scaled differently. If you change it to a larger size, `.extraLargeTitle` will not change much, but `.caption1` would be a lot larger, because captions are usually smaller than "extra large titles" :D

I think you misunderstood what the purpose of `UIFontMetrics` is. It is not for determining the suitable font size for a text style (you should determine this yourself), but for determining how much to *scale* an existing font, based on the dynamic type size setting and text style.

When the dynamic type size is the default setting, no scaling is needed, and you will always get the same font size you passed in (in this case,`UIFont.systemFontSize`).

When the dynamic type size setting changes, different `TextStyle`s are scaled differently - that's what the `forTextStyle` parameter is for.

If you want your font's font size to always match the system fonts for a given `TextStyle` (not recommended), see the specification [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography#Specifications). Take the sizes in the "Large (Default)" column, and use that instead of `UIFont.systemFontSize` in your code.

If you use a custom font, it is natural to also design your own font sizes for each text style, and not rely on the ones designed for the system font. While the ones for the system font looks good on the system font, it might not be suitable for your custom font.

```
func customFont(forStyle style: UIFont.TextStyle) -> UIFont {
    let fontSize: CGFloat
    switch style {
    // here, decide what size you want to use for each text style.
    // you can use the sizes for the system font as I linked above
    // if you really want to
    case .body:
        fontSize = ...
    case .caption1:
        fontSize = ...
    // etc
    }
    guard let font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: fontSize) else { fatalError("No font found") }
    return UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: style).scaledFont(for: font)
}
```

Comment: So, you're saying that for standard size title2 and caption2 both will be 14pt? Take a look in screenshot which is provided in Question. Also take a look link that you provided, select medium size (which is default) and observe font size for title2 and caption2.

Comment: @MrugeshTank No, `UIFontMetrics` is not for getting the “standard size”, whatever that means. It is for *scaling* a font. You said `size: UIFont.systemFontSize` and `UIFont.systemFontSize` is 14, and there is no scaling needed, according to your dynamic type size setting, so the size stays at 14. All the different sizes you are talking about are *sizes specifically for the system font*. If you are using your own font, the standard size for each text style need not be these same as those for the system font. You can (and IMO should) decide the sizes for each text style yourself.

Comment: @MrugeshTank as you said in the comments, you can just use `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:).pointSize` to get the sizes for the system font. Those sizes work for system fonts but they might not work with your own font, but if you just want your own font to use the same sizes for the system font, feel free to keep using `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)`. Use `UIFontMetrics`, only when you have a particular-sized font that you want to scale.

Comment: @MrugeshTank yes, title2 and caption2 have different sizes, ***for the system font***. For your own font, Montserrat, you have decided that it should have `UIFont.systemFontSize` (this is a constant) for all text styles. That is what your code is saying. See the code snippet in my answer, you should decide a font size for each text style, for Monsterrat. Feel free to use the same sizes as the system font, which you can get from the specifications.

Comment: @MrugeshTank see also the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics/2877385-scaledfont). Quote: “Set the size of your font to the standard Dynamic Type size that you use for the corresponding content”. You set it to `UIFont.systemFontSize`, which is 14. It returns a font “scaled to the current Dynamic Type setting” and your dynamic type setting is the default one, so no scaling is needed.